# .NET 6 Upgrade Broke DinkToPdf on Azure Function

Tags: c#, azure, linker, .net-6.0, wkhtmltopdf

I've got an Azure Function (not container function) that uses DinkToPdf.

I've upgraded this to .NET 6 and Azure V4.

I now get this error:

```
One or more errors occurred. (Unable to load shared library '/home/site/wwwroot/bin/libwkhtmltox.so' or one of its dependencies. In order to help diagnose loading problems, consider setting the LD_DEBUG environment variable: libXrender.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
```

I've checked the deployed bundle and `libqkhtmltox.so` exists, so reading further down the error, I assume that `libXrender.so.1` is missing on the system.

I've seen various other answers on here that suggest just `apt install libxrender1` to fix this, but since I'm not in a containerised function, I don't think I can do that.

Are there any workarounds here?

Has `libXrender` been upgraded in V4, if so, can I manually load in `libXrender.so.x` and hope it works? Is there a nuget package I can use to bundle in `libXrender.so.1`?

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution?

Comment: Sort of... I had to migrate to a function with a custom runtime container and add the dependencies to that. I'll do a write-up later.

Comment: Ah, that would be amazing. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Had a bit of time, just did it now. If you have any questions, let me know and I'll add them to the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems as though Microsoft has removed a whole bunch of dependencies around `libgdiplus` from the standard runtime container. I'm sure those aren't the only ones.

So, the answer is to migrate your function to [use a custom runtime container](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-function-linux-custom-image).

This dockerfile should do the job:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS installer-env    
COPY . /src/dotnet-function-app
RUN cd /src/dotnet-function-app && \
    mkdir -p /home/site/wwwroot && \
    dotnet publish your-project.csproj --output /home/site/wwwroot


FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/dotnet:4
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libglib2.0 libgdiplus libnss3 libatk1.0-0 libatk-bridge2.0-0 ca-certificates fonts-liberation libappindicator3-1 libasound2 libatk-bridge2.0-0 libatk1.0-0 libc6 libcairo2 libcups2 libdbus-1-3 libexpat1 libfontconfig1 libgbm1 libgcc1 libglib2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libnspr4 libnss3 libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libstdc++6 libx11-6 libx11-xcb1 libxcb1 libxcomposite1 libxcursor1 libxdamage1 libxext6 libxfixes3 libxi6 libxrandr2 libxrender1 libxss1 libxtst6 lsb-release xdg-utils
ENV AzureWebJobsScriptRoot=/home/site/wwwroot \
    AzureFunctionsJobHost__Logging__Console__IsEnabled=true  

COPY --from=installer-env ["/home/site/wwwroot", "/home/site/wwwroot"]
```

I'm not saying this is the optimal container, but it does contain everything needed for both `pupetteer`/`chrome-headless` and `dink2pdf` to work. If you just want `dink2pdf`, you might only need `libgdiplus` in that dependency install line (I've not tested it though).